# How to write which day is today in Java?

Tags: java

I want to write today's day to the console. E.g., if today is Monday, write `"Monday"` to the console. I am new to Java so I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: Ok, here is the plan: you first try to write a basic Java program, read/watch some tutorials, if that works out, you should use Google to check whether this problem has been solved before and if it is, you can try out that solution for yourself. If at that point, you stumble upon problems that you cannot resolve, post your code with problem here on StackOverflow and we will help you out. Good luck!

Comment: So the first thing you do is pick up a book or online tutorial about Java. Then you do some research. Then you make an attempt. If you run into a *specific* problem, ask about that. More: [tour], [help], [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -3):

You can try something like:

```
public class GetDayFromDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Date now = new Date();

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("E"); // the day of the week abbreviated
        System.out.println(simpleDateformat.format(now));

        simpleDateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE"); // the day of the week spelled out completely
        System.out.println(simpleDateformat.format(now));

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(now);
        System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)); // the day of the week in numerical format

    }
}
```

Comment: Strongly recommend **not** answering questions that are going to be closed and deleted. First and foremost, it encourages rubbish questions like this one. Second, it's a waste of your time. *(Removed my dv, though; this is now an answer.)*